# How to find out if an external headset is connected to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio

Is it possible to detect that the user has an external headset plugged into the iPhone's 3.5mm connector or the 30-pin connector? I want to output audio only to an external audio device, and keep silent if nothing is connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is very similar to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667196/detecting-iphone-ipod-touch-accessories), but you'll want to get the [kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute) property instead.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need. Now I wonder what are the possible values for the Auidio_Route property.

Comment: For possible values, see this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753562/what-kind-of-routes-could-i-get-back-from-kaudiosessionproperty-audioroute-proper

Answer (score 2):

Call this method to find out the bluetooth headset is connected or not.

First import this framework  `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

```
- (BOOL) isBluetoothHeadsetConnected
    {
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        AVAudioSessionRouteDescription *routeDescription = [session currentRoute];

        NSLog(@"Current Routes : %@", routeDescription);

        if (routeDescription)
        {
            NSArray *outputs = [routeDescription outputs];

            if (outputs && [outputs count] > 0)
            {
                AVAudioSessionPortDescription *portDescription = [outputs objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *portType = [portDescription portType];

                NSLog(@"dataSourceName : %@", portType);

                if (portType && [portType isEqualToString:@"BluetoothA2DPOutput"])
                {
                    return YES;
                }
            }
        }

        return NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nice article about this in Apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_route_changes

Only you have to verify if portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP

```
func setupNotifications() {
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                               selector: #selector(handleRouteChange),
                               name: .AVAudioSessionRouteChange,
                               object: nil)
}


@objc func handleRouteChange(notification: Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let reasonValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? UInt,
        let reason = AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason(rawValue:reasonValue) else {
            return
    }
    switch reason {
    case .newDeviceAvailable:
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        for output in session.currentRoute.outputs where output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP {
            headsetConnected = true
            break
        }
    case .oldDeviceUnavailable:
        if let previousRoute =
            userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey] as? AVAudioSessionRouteDescription {
            for output in previousRoute.outputs where output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP {
                headsetConnected = false
                break
            }
        }
    default: ()
    }
}

func isBluetoothHeadsetConnected() -> Bool {
    var result = false
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    for output in session.currentRoute.outputs where output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP {
        result = true
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the [essential parts of the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)