# What kind of routes could I get back from kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute property?

Tags: iphone, audio, openal, audiosession

Apple guy tried to be funny and wrote in the docs:

```
("Headphone," "Speaker," etc.)
```

What kind of return values are possible in reality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He wasn't being funny, those are actual values.  The only one I've seen that he didn't outline is "LineOut"

Comment: the funny part is the etc., so you have to guess what other strings might be returned.

Comment: More funny is, on iOS 3.1.2 the values change, now we have: "SpeakerAndMicrophone" and so on... Nice compatibility folks.

Answer (score 11):

I ran 'strings' on the CoreMedia framework (iOS4.2 SDK), and the following strings seem reasonable and are grouped together:

- ReceiverAndMicrophone
- HeadsetInOut
- HeadphonesAndMicrophone
- SpeakerAndMicrophone
- HeadsetBT
- LineInOut
- Default

Command was:

```
strings -a -o CoreMedia | less

# CoreMedia is from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer \
# /SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework
```

Answer (score 2):

According to http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Jan/msg00084.html
there are also LineOut,  HeadsetInOut, ReceiverAndMicrophone, HeadphonesAndMicrophone,
but the guy who asked whether there are more values received no answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just got MicrophoneWired from it. (I actually have a special piece of hardware plugged in that is a temperature probe, but we are using it through the headphone jack).

Then I got MicrophoneBuiltIn with nothing plugged in. This is on an ipod touch with 4.3 by the way.

Comment: I get the same (MicrophoneWired / MicrophoneBuiltIn) when I've used kAudioSessionCategory_RecordAudio as my audio category and I plug and unplug a headset (headphones with built-in mic).

Answer (score 0):

The values provided by l8nite above are reserved for when your audio session is configured for both input and output. Other values used when you're only doing audio out: (I used the same trick as l8nite - thanks!)

LineOut

HeadphonesBT (used for Bluetooth audio output - observed this hooked up to via bluetooth to a car audio system)

AirTunes (used for AirPlay output)

Answer (score 0):

How is HeadphonesBT different from HeadsetBT ? My app could successfully use the HeadsetBT device to send and receive audio while HeadphonesBT failed to do anything. This is on iOs6