# Do we have a builtin Bluetooth connection listener in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, callback

We want to set a call-back function (or listener) to trigger some functionalities when a paired bluetooth device is connected to iPhone. I've found some related answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231573/iphone-how-to-know-if-bluetooth-headset-connected), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520296/how-can-i-find-out-if-an-external-headset-is-connected-to-an-iphone), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667196/detecting-iphone-ipod-touch-accessories), but all of them seem quite old.

Do we have a builtin or external library in iOS that enables an app to automatically check if a Bluetooth device is connected or not?

Any input will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could observe the `inputAvailable` property of an `AVAudioSession` object via `NSNotificationCenter`.